# I have restarted My Django for Other Project But it's still trying to load Previous project files

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, virtualenv, django-migrations

I have worked on Django Project where I create applications hello, newyear, and tasks. Now, I have to
work on a different Project I got it's file from CMD I opened it in visual studio and then created a
virtual environment and installed Django in it, but When I have run the server it's showing this output: in the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1loDw.png)

it's trying to open the previous project files instead this project. However, the ip address given by
django was same for both projects.

Please help, I am new to programing.

thank you very much

I am trying to create django server for the project file I download online from a course cs50web
So, I can run that project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your old project server is still running. Stop it with `Ctr+C`. Then start the server of your new project.

Comment: Yeah!, I did it and It worked out Thanks Bro.

Answer (score 0):

You have no path for `/` in your lecture3.url, which is expected.
Try to visit `/admin`, `/hello`, or other URLs mentioned in your error - they should work fine.
If you want to render something at `/`, create an entry for that in your `urls` file.

Comment: brother these(/hello, /newyear) urls are from my previous django project. Now, I am trying to create a server for new project who's name is wiki and it is in different folder and have a different urls.py file, and Django is using wiki.settings however it's showing this error the image I have sent.